# How do I deploy a Keras model on mobile devices using DART and Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, keras, dart

What are the basic steps would be to deploy keras model on mobile devices using Flutter? What should I consider here? A quick guideline would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do your mean by "deploy a keras model using Flutter" ? Do you want to execute it ? Do you want to publish it somewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert your model to tensorflow lite (provided all the operations in your model are supported in tflite). 
The below link gives a complete demo on how an object detection model can be ported to mobile device via flutter. In place of the object detection model , you can use your custom model. 
be wary of the input type, and the output type when you convert to tf lite.

https://blog.francium.tech/real-time-object-detection-on-mobile-with-flutter-tensorflow-lite-and-yolo-android-part-a0042c9b62c6